# PHP/PDO Connecting to Mysql, but query does not appear to be executed

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**Hello Stack Overflow!** 
Im trying to connect to a database and update a certain set of records dependent on the information sent to the web server. When I execute the PHP page and get a result of no errors, nothing updates on the database. As if the query did not even execute. Also I can manually execute it, it works fine like you would expect. The PDO driver connection is setup correctly and does not declare an error.

**My Code:**

(The Connection Information is declared in a separate database.php file, as well as the table names. This is only the part of the code that interacts on the part  that malfunctions.)

```js
<? php
include "database.php";
$conn = new MySQLi($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

if ($conn - > connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: ".$conn - > connect_error);
}
$conp = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;port=3306;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);
$conp - > setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conp - > setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
    try {
      $sql = null;
      $sql1 = $conp - > prepare("UPDATE `".$tbl_bans_name.
        "` SET `resolved`='1' WHERE `Date`=':date' AND `Reason`=':reason'");
      $sql1 - > bindParam(':date', $date);
      $sql1 - > bindParam(':reason', $reason);
      if ($sql1 - > execute()) {
        echo "good";
      }
      $sql1 = null;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      print_r($e);
    }
    //$execute = Mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
    //mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Any and all help is appreciated! I would be grateful because this problem has been troubling me for the past few hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should correct this row, by removing ' around :date & :reason - like this:

```
 "` SET `resolved`='1' WHERE `Date`=:date AND `Reason`=:reason");
```

Comment: Thanks alot! That fixed the issue, I will have to keep this in mind for future coding! Didnt realize that you couldn't put the quotes around a placeholder.